# Firebase Firestore TTL Policy for nested collections

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ttl

Is there any way to create a TTL Policy (In Preview) for a nested collection?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The TTL policy works by [querying on collection groups](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), which means you have to specify `posts` as the collection name and it them will clean up the documents in all `posts` collections regardless of where they exist in the database.

If you have `posts` collections in multiple paths and don't want to expire content from all of them, consider giving them more unique names, such as `profile_posts` for the ones under `profiles`. Alternatively, use a field that is unique for the TTL that you want to enforce, which is only present in documents you actually want to get auto-deleted.

Comment: I was expecting something similar as we have at Cloud Functions: functions.firestore.document("profiles/{id}/posts").onCreate(...)

Comment: But even better, if it works like you mentioned! Thank you Frank! ;)